# format the source code from TAB to Space

Tags: visual-studio

VS2010 IDE: Downloaded some source code from internet and the project is tab formatted. How can I change it to be use white space instead of tabs?

Answer (score 3):

Edit -> Advanced -> Untabify Selected Lines